# VS Team Services trigger option on build pipeline for external git repository

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines

I have a unauthenticated (in vsts) external git repository that works in an local agent pool (who is auth) that is external too. Our build pipepline is the connection with our certificates that does this solution work.

The problem here is that there is no possibility to trigger automatically when someone push some changes on the master branch on this external unauthenticated (in vsts) git repository.

For this trigger option, there is only this configuration:

[image]

But after this, if someone push an commit, nothing happen.

Is there a limitation? Any configuration that I need to get this working? At now, it's always done manually to stat the build pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the continuous integration with External Git, VSTS will connect to your external repository and check if there is new changes by the polling interval time you set. So you must configure the authentication in VSTS so that VSTS can access to your Git Repository to query new changes. When you configure the external git repository, it should ask you to provide user and password/token, enter the auth information there.

Comment: I assume that there is no way to check this polling interval from the agent pool. The restriction here is that we can't have the permission to auth this external git from our VSTS.

Comment: @soydachi Yes, there isn't any way so far. You can consider to create a script to check the changes in your repo and then queue the VSTS build via Rest API.